# Delete column from xls file

Tags: python-3.x, xls, xlrd

Using Python, I need to be able to do the following operations to a workbook for excel 2007:

1.delete colums

I am looking into xlrd; however.

Can anyone please tell me how could do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're working in Python 3.x, you'll find a lot of trouble using the `xlrd`/`xlwt`/`xlutils` family, as they're modules for Python 2.

You might consider **[openpyxl](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/index.html)** for working with Excel 2007 .xlsx files in Python 3.

If you just need to shift values over (disregarding formatting, etc) here's one way to do it. You can build on this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.cell import column_index_from_string as col_index
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter as col_letter

def del_col(s, col, cmax=None, rmax=None):
    col_num = col_index(col) - 1
    cols = s.columns
    if isinstance(cmax, str):
        cmax = col_index(cmax)
    cmax = cmax or s.get_highest_column()
    rmax = rmax or s.get_highest_row()
    for c in range(col_num, cmax + 1):
        # print("working on column %i" % c)
        for r in range(0, rmax):
            cols[c][r].value = cols[c+1][r].value
    for r in range(0, rmax):
        cols[c+1][r].value = ''

    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wb = load_workbook('input_book.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active
    # or by name: ws = wb['SheetName']
    col = 'D'
    del_col(ws, col)
    wb.save('output_book.xlsx')
```

Comment: This did not work for me; I got the error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment`.

Comment: I got the same error, any fix for that?

Comment: Might be late to the party, but that error is probably thrown when col_num <= cmax - 1, so the first for loop never gets entered and c never gets a value.  The second for loop uses c so the error is thrown.   I'm pretty sure the first for loop is supposed to have range(col_num, cmax + 1).

Comment: This does not appropriately answer the question, since openpyxl only works with xlsx, not with xls which was specified in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This deletes a column from an xlsx worksheet using [openpyxl 2.3.3](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.3/index.html).  You can specify either a column number or letter:

```
import openpyxl.cell

def delete_column(ws, delete_column):
    if isinstance(delete_column, str):
        delete_column = openpyxl.cell.column_index_from_string(delete_column)
    assert delete_column >= 1, "Column numbers must be 1 or greater"

    for column in range(delete_column, ws.max_column + 1):
        for row in range(1, ws.max_row + 1):
            ws.cell(row=row, column=column).value = \
                    ws.cell(row=row, column=column+1).value
```

On its final iteration this copies `None` values from column `ws.max_column+1` to column `ws.max_column`, wiping out the values that used to be there.  While the values in the cells are correct, unfortunately `ws.max_column` does not decrement.

In other answers there is talk of using `Worksheet.garbage_collect()` to reset `ws.max_column`, but I could only find the private method `Worksheet._garbage_collect()`, so I did not use it.

UPDATE:
In the end I found that deleting a lot of columns was inefficient.  Hiding them is a superior solution.  This preserves formatting and even more importantly, maintains the integrity of formulae that reference the hidden cells:

```
def hide_column(ws, column_id):
    if isinstance(column_id, int):
        assert column_id >= 1, "Column numbers must be 1 or greater"
        column_id = openpyxl.cell.get_column_letter(column_id)
    column_dimension = ws.column_dimensions[column_id]
    column_dimension.hidden = True
```

Comment: Cannot delete multiple files

Comment: Worked great for me, thanks!  The accepted answer had some issues as noted in the comments for that answer, but this did what I needed it to.  Thanks!

Comment: I prefer this solution to the accepted one!