# existing Xlsx file delete specific Columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, xlsx

I am trying to remove a column from a xlsx file i have.

What i tried to do and founded over the internet was to write down in specific cells in order to clean its values but couldn't find a faster way to remove the whole column.

what i did was this but since i have 300 rows its going to be large...

```
import openpyxl
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('excel.xlsx')

sheet = xfile.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet['B1'] = ''
sheet['B2'] = ''
sheet['B3'] = ''
sheet['B4'] = ''
sheet['B5'] = ''
sheet['B6'] = ''

xfile.save('output.xlsx')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what error u r getting?

Comment: [pop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) modifies the dataframe passed and returns the deleted item. So you don't have to assign the return to a new variable but just save the original one.

Comment: Here is an example how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048016/delete-column-from-xls-file

Comment: Already tested he's using .cells thats wrong and old should be .utils .... @Ugnius Malūkas and later there are more porblems on the program...